# XXX is not defined - Importing Class from OpenLayers Node Module in Django

Tags: node.js, django, node-modules, openlayers

Having difficulty getting the Node `OpenLayers` to work within Django. `npm` and `ol` are installed and the files are in a `node_modules` folder in my project. I included the `node_modules` folder in my `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`.

I'm including the `OpenLayers` modules within my template, `map.html`:

```
<script type="module" src="{% static 'ol/dist/ol.js' %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'ol/Map.js' %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'ol/View.js' %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'ol/layer/Tile.js' %}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{% static 'ol/source/OSM.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    import "{% static 'ol/layer/Tile.js' %}";
    const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'my-map',
        layers: [
            new ol.Layer.Tile({
                source: ol.Source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [40, -70],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
</script>
```

Which appears to be working as I can see the files load within my browser's dev tools.

But when I try to use the classes within the modules I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined
```

---

---

OTHER METHODS I'VE TRIED:

I've also tried calling the class names directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const map = new Map({
        target: 'my-map',
        layers: [
            new Tile({
                source: OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new View({
            center: [40, -70],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
</script>
```

But get the same error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tile is not defined
```

---

The OpenLayers docs show using the import statement:

```
import "{% static 'ol/layer/Tile.js' %}";
```

but when I try that I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use an import statement outside a module
```

---

I've also found recommendations to try:

```
const Tile = require("{% static 'ol/layer/Tile.js' %}");
```

but get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Require is not defined
```

Comment: `ol/dist/ol.js` is the full build and should include everything. It is not a module, so remove the type attribute from its script tag and remove all other ol script tags. Use the full build with dot-separated class path, e. g. `new ol.Map({ /* ... */ })`.

Comment: @MoonE That makes sense - and works perfectly. Don't know how to mark this as the answer as it's a comment. Thank you!